# How to use traditional (national/native) dates and calendars?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

How can use non-Gregorian dates and calendars?

I adjust Drupal setting to my native language (fa) and native location (Asia/Theran) but month name and number of years also in Gregorian yet (however there are translated to my native language-persian).

I already use `format_date()` or `date()` in theme files, but this function is not locale-aware, which means that it always outputs English language data, such as day and month names and ordinal number suffixes.

I want to show the month names in the native language (e.g. Chinese, Islamic, Hebrew, Farsi/Persian) and use the national calendar (e.g. Irani, Shamsi, Jalali).

I want to understand is there any module or hardcoding solution in Drupal to show dates and calendars in other non-Gregorian calendars.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried passing in a $langcode? What are you system.date settings in configuration?

Comment: `format_date` is deprecated anyway, don't use it - use `\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format()` instead. That's a service, which you can replace, so nothing stopping you from 'replacing' this with your own or a different class. You'll need to make sure it stays compatible with the rest of Drupal, of course

Comment: This change record may be helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/1834108

Answer (score 8):

I'm hoping that someone else can Optimize this solution and make it better.
I'm ready to receive Any suggestion or criticism or any Other solution for this Challenge.

### Features:

- Does not requires any hacking or patching core /frontend solution
  ,display when dates are rendered
- Does not change any date in database
- Compatible and tested with PHP versions 5.3 and hereinafter
- Supports Iranian/Persian/Shamsi/Jalali , Arabic/Hijri/Islamic, Thai, Hebrew...
  Calendar systems
- Better Performance becuse Doesn't outbreak the drupal core

### **Method 1, Using "IntelDateFormatter" Class:**

First of all you must be sure that version of your php that installed is Newer than 5.3 and **'IntlDateFormatter'** Extension was exist.
For use Traditional(National/Native) Date/Calender in **Drupal 8** in nodes and Posted Comments with use of IntlDateFormatter class, add below codes to "THEME_NAME.theme":

For Nodes:

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $locale = "fa_IR@calendar=persian";
    $dateType = IntlDateFormatter::NONE;//type of date formatting.
    $timeType = IntlDateFormatter::NONE;//if time format setting to none, will give you date itself
    $timezone = 'Asia/Tehran';
    $calendar = IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL;//Non-Gregorian Calendar
    $pattern = 'y/M/d';

    $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $dateType, $timeType, $timezone, $calendar, $pattern);
    $date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();    
    $variables['date'] = $fmt->format($date);
}
```

For Comments:

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
    $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    "fa_IR@calendar=persian",
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'Asia/Tehran',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    'y/M/d'
    );

    // Getting the node creation time stamp from the comment object.
    $date = $variables['comment']->getCreatedTime();
    $variables['created'] = $fmt->format($date);
}
```

Information about "IntlDateFormatter" Parameters:
**locale:**
 Locale to use when formatting or parsing or NULL to use the value specified in the ini setting, Link:http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags

**datetype:**
Date type to use (NONE, FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT). This is one of the IntlDateFormatter constants.

**timetype:**
 
Time type to use (NONE, FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT). This is one of the IntlDateFormatter constants.

**timezone:**
 
Time zone ID, default is system default, 
Link:http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

**calendar:**
 
Calendar to use for formatting or parsing; default is Gregorian. This is one of the IntlDateFormatter calendar constants.
The calendars ICU allows you to play with include:

- Japanese (@calendar=japanese)
- Buddhist (@calendar=buddhist)
- Chinese (@calendar=chinese)
- Persian (@calendar=persian)
- Indian (@calendar=indian)
- Islamic (@calendar=islamic)
- Hebrew (@calendar=hebrew)
- Coptic (@calendar=coptic)
- Ethiopic (@calendar=ethiopic)

Link:http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/calendar

**pattern:**
 
Optional pattern to use when formatting or parsing. Possible patterns are documented at: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

---

### **METHOD 2,Using External Functions (like "jdf" for persian language):**

First download this function form: http://jdf.scr.ir/download/
and then put downloaded file to your theme folder and add this code to above of "Theme_Name.theme"

```
include ('jdf.php');
```

and then add below code to appropriate place:

```
function Theme_Name_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   $date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();
   $variables['date'] = jdate("l j F Y", strtotime($date));
}
```

I'm hoping that someone else can build on this and make it better.

Answer (score 2):

[Taarikh](https://www.drupal.org/project/taarikh) module will help you use the Islamic calendar as a field formatter and widget for display with the ability to translate month names, I used it and works very well, it's the best for Islamic calendar.

You could patch the module to add support for other calendars "i could help"

Comment: https://github.com/mgomma/taarikh

Comment: Sure you could patch the module and push your code, I could add you as a contributor on github and work with you on that issue, By the way the module maintainer have another approach to add any calendar system but not working yet and I contacted him to contribute and publish it, let me know your mail address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Modules:

### **Calendar Systems**

**Module page:** [Calendar Systems](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_systems)
**Support:** Iranian (jalali) , Arabic/Islamic/Hijri , Thai and Gregorian (Using PHP's built-in)
**Version:** Drupal 7
**BY:** [Sina Salek](https://www.linkedin.com/in/sinasalek)
**Description:**

> Advances Drupal's already awesome localization support one more big step ahead by Adding support for different calendar
>   systems like Iranian , Jalali , Hijir , Thai , Hebrew etc. This
>   support is currently limited to display and data entry for date fields
>   and the back-end date is always Gregorian (Timestamp).

---

### **Datex**

**Module page:** [Datex](https://www.drupal.org/project/datex)
**Support:** only Iranian (Hijri Shamsi/ jalali)
**Version:** Drupal 7
**By:** [Drupalion](http://drupalion.com/blog/177)
**Description:**

> Datex and related module will help to create a better multilingual
>   website for languages needing a Jalali (Or in near feature of datex,
>   any) calendar instead of default Gregorian calendar.

---

### **Hijri**

**Module page:** [Hijri](https://www.drupal.org/project/hijri)
**Support:** Only Hijri Date (Islamic, Hijri Ghamari)
**Version:** Drupal 7, Drupal 8 (Development releases)
**By:** [Abdullah Bamelhes](https://www.linkedin.com/in/bamlhs)
**Description:**

> This is a smart module that basically extends Drupal's display date to
>   provide Hijri Date integration with Drupal core date field and with
>   other Drupal contributions.
>
> This module is integrated very well with Views module

---

### Taarikh

**Module page:**[Taarikh](https://www.drupal.org/project/taarikh)
**Support:** Only Hijri Date (Islamic, Hijri Ghamari)
**Version:** Drupal 7, Drupal 8 (Development releases)
**By:** [Husain Inad](http://linkedin.com/in/husainad)
**Description:**

> Taarikh is a field formatter and widget module to display and input
>   hijri dates using the fields defined by the date module. The formatter
>   can work with all the fields defined by the date module, i.e., Date,
>   Date (ISO format) and Date (Unix timestamp). The widget, however, does
>   not work with Date (Unix timestamp).

Comment: The question is about drupal 8 and you suggest drupal 7 modules !!!